# Angular (6) and d3 (v5): components as subelements in one svg and passing svg element to each component

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I am using **Angular 6** and **d3 v5**.
I have created a *Glyph* component with html template

```
<svg:g #glyph></svg:g>
```

and in order to add svg elements using `d3`, in the .ts file I have `selector: '[glyph]'` and

```
@ViewChild('glyph') private glyphContainer : ElementRef;
...
const glyphElement = this.glyphContainer.nativeElement;
d3.select(glyphElement).append("svg:rect")
...
```

In the parent component I can use `<svg glyph></svg>` to show this.

---

I want to add multiple instances of this *Glyph* component into the same svg, for instance, in a *GlyphList* component. In order to manage `d3` selections, transitions, and interaction, I want each individual component to be part of the same `svg` (or better yet, part of the same `svg:g` element).

As an example, imagine that I am creating a visualization on a file system and *Glyph* is a custom `svg:g` UI element visualizing a particular file or folder, and I have a directory of files that I want visualized with a *GlyphList* component, all in the same `svg`.

**How can I do this in Angular?** Namely, how do I structure the template and initiate each *Glyph* component and pass in a shared `svg` element in a *GlyphList* component (or service?) that I can select with `d3` in each of the child components?

Answer (score -1):

Check this tutorial, in the section SVG Components with Angular, there is a section of how to do exactly what you are asking for.

https://medium.com/netscape/visualizing-data-with-angular-and-d3-209dde784aeb

```
<svg>
    <g [lineExample]></g>
</svg>
```

And your svg component:
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: '[lineExample]',
    template: `<svg:line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"></svg:line>`
})
export class LineExampleComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

However, I end up here because I can't make it work, Angular gives me this error

```
compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'lineExample' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:g'. ("<svg>
    <g [ERROR ->][lineExample]></g>
</svg>"): ng:///AppModule/TrackComponent.html@1:7
```

Let me know if you make it work!